# How to change default User authentication Allow message and logo in Dropbox using dropbox API?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Please check this [link](http://www.codehandling.com/2013/02/install-login-with-dropbox-on-your.html) : I'm using the same OAuth Javascriptfor Dropbox API

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Which is your question?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://twitter.com/maraimalais/status/618382787717038080 ]

Answer (score 0):

You can not get this done via API. If you want your app logo to be changed, go to Dropbox App Console->YourApp->Details tab and then choose the icon and name of your Dropbox application.